# Recovering from failure with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

working with dockerode (a docker module) I need to implement the following workflow:

1. create container
2. if creation fails, pull container, then create container
3. run container

so it looks roughly like:

```
docker.createContainer()
   .catch(function (e) { 
     return docker.pull()
        .then(function() { return docker.createContainer() };
   }).then(function(o) { o.start(); });
```

which is not very DRY.  is there any way to clean this up?

Comment: Where are you repeating yourself? Putting `docker.createContainer` in an extra function would probably be even more verbose.

Answer (score 2):

What's not DRY about that? - The only thing DRYer would be using es6 arrow functions:

```
docker.createContainer()
   .catch(e => docker.pull().then(() => docker.createContainer()))
   .then(o => o.start());
```

The only repetition here is in your original expression of the problem, which I don't think can be made DRYer.

Comment: it's not DRY because I've repeated myself with the call to `createContainer`, but perhaps it cannot be written more concisely

Comment: It matches your desired workflow exactly, which I think is as good as you can hope for. Can you describe it without repeating yourself?

Comment: yeah... I guess it can't be done.  what I've done is reworked the logic to check whether the container already exists and then not try the creation.  I would mark you answer to close this question if you stated simple that my original expression cannot be made dryer